# Is there something like has_no_term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type named 'Projecten' with a taxonomy called 'fases_projecten', in there  i have 'concept', 'inontwikkeling' and 'gerealiseerd'.
In my template I'm using the following code for displaying changes between the sevral fases/terms.

```
`<?php  if( has_term( 'concept', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status sActiveConcept"><?php } ?>`
```

For each fase I have a diffrent openingdiv class, but maybe it will happen that the users of the website forget to choose a fase, witch mess up the site completely because the openingtag of the div is missing.

So I was wondering if there exsists something like has no term.

What I already tried is

```
<?php   if( has_term( '', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status"><?php } ?>
```

Also when I make do it like this:

```
<?php   if( has_term( 'concept', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status sActiveConcept"><?php } ?>
<?php   elseif( has_term( 'inontwikkeling', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status sActiveDeveloping"><?php } ?>
<?php   elseif( has_term( 'gerealiseerd', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status sActiveFinished"><?php } ?>
<?php   else( has_term( '', 'fases_projecten' ) ) { ?><div class="status"><?php } ?>
```

It will not work, I get a servererror.

I hope I explained clear enough, my english is not so good though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

```
if (false === get_the_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag' )) {
  // has no post tags at all
}
```

I am not sure there is an existing core function to test specifically for the absence of any term at all including custom taxonomies but you can pass an array of taxonomies as the second parameter, meaning you could use [`get_taxonomies()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) to do:

```
if (false === get_the_terms( $post_id, get_the_terms( 1, get_taxonomies('','names') ) )) {
  // has no post tags at all
}
```

`$post_id` must be set to the a post ID to be checked for terms.

Comment: Doesn't work eighter.
Maybe I'm doing something diffrent wrong, but I can't figure out what.

I tried

`<?php if (false === get_the_terms( 1, 'fases_projecten' )) {     ?>
    <div class="status">
    <?php } ?>`


And


`if (false === get_the_terms( 1, get_the_terms( 1, get_taxonomies('','fases_projecten') ) )) {
  <div class="status">
}`

Comment: Sorry. Editing mistake on my part. The first parameter of `get_the_terms` is a post ID. I did not remove the ID I was using to test the code. `get_taxonomies` should be exactly as written in my code. The second parameter _is not_ your taxonomy name. A bad term name will return a WP_Error object rather than false, so the code could be more robust.

Comment: Thank you =D
The first option works for me:)

I now put 
    `$postid = get_the_ID();`
at top of the page and used

`<?php if (false === get_the_terms( $postid, 'fases_projecten' )) { ?> <div class="status"> <?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `else` so your last lines would become:

`<?php else { ?><div class="status"><?php } ?>`

Comment: I get a server error with that :(

Does else also work if you have 3 ifs above them, I mean, for all ifs?
or is it only for the last if?

Comment: Then you have something else which produces the error. The if/else loop looks correct.

Comment: Oke, thanks, I'm gonna try to search it out, thanks for helping :)

Comment: You're welcome. Post your solution here, when you get it working.

Comment: Already did :)

The solution  of s_ha_dum worked =D